# Python glitch with for loop

Tags: python

i write a code to separate int from the list

when i write the code that way not working

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'Ahmed','Mustafa',100,103,107]
list_b = []

x = 0
for item in list_a:
    if isinstance(item, int):
        list_b.append(item)
        list_a.pop(x)
    x +=1


print (list_a)
print (list_b)
print (x)
```

and that`s my output

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 'Ahmed', 'Mustafa', 103]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 100, 107]
8
```

and the code work in this way

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'Ahmed','Mustafa',100,103,107]
list_b = []
list_d = []

x = 0
for item in list_a:
    if isinstance(item, int):
        list_b.append(item)
    else :
        list_d.append(item)
    x +=1


print (list_a)
print (list_b)
print (list_d)
print (x)
```

why that glitch happened ?

Comment: Whats the output in the second case?

Comment: You're iterating over a list.  Modifying the list inside the loop interferes with the iteration.  Does anyone have a reference to one of the duplicates for this question?  I'm not finding the right search keys today.  :-(

Comment: You can't `pop` an item while iterating, it changes the size of the iterator. You would have to work off of a copy if you wanted to remove items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: The second code is working fine if you want you can check it [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/live.html#mode=edit)

Comment: you can simply store the index for pop to a list and after getting int list pop elements from first using that list of index.

Comment: use `list(filter(lambda i: isinstance(i, int), list_a))` to get the list of integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logically**

The list `pop` method pops from an index and removes it. After index 0 is gone, the next index you have to pop is... 0! Since the element in index 0 is gone, the element that should be deleted next has moved to be the new index 0.

Incrementing `x` every time popped 0 in the first iteration, then 1 (that was the third element in the original list). That's how you lost some elements from being iterated (you simply removed them before they were iterated by the `for` loop).

**Practically**

The real problem is the `pop`ping itself. When you iterate through an *iterable*, you should not be modifying it. If you wanted to remove the integers from the original list, have two loops - one for adding the integers to the second list, second to remove them from the first list.